# Cellcolor doesn't color full cell in custom longtable caption definition

Tags: tables, color, captions, longtable, multicolumn

To create a caption in a `longtable` multicolumn table cell with a grey background I changed the `\LT@makecaption` from the original package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% redefine longtable caption
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
    \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{#2: }\textbf{#3}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \caption{My Table Caption}\label{table1} \\
    \hline
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    3 & 4\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

By looking at the compiled version, it doesn't color the full table width with the grey background. LaTeX adds a small white space (margin / padding ?) on the right side of the cell.

[image]

How can I avoid this to color the full table width of the cell width the right border on the right side, without any margin / padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are explicitly adding two space tokens in your code, without them you get

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% redefine longtable caption
\makeatletter
\def\LT@makecaption#1#2#3{%
    \multicolumn{\LT@cols}{|c|}{\cellcolor{gray!40}\textbf{#2: }\textbf{#3}}%%%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \caption{My Table Caption}\label{table1}\\
    \hline
    1 & 2\\ \hline
    3 & 4\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```